# How to create file in java/android from dataURL which is generated using JavaScript

Tags: java, android

How to create file in java/android from dataURL which is generated using JavaScript

Zip File

```
data:application/x-zip-compressed;base64,LS1Lb1pJaHZjTkFRY0INCkNvbnRlbnQtRGlzcG9zaXRpb...
```

Image File    `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT.......==`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String bas64String="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT.......=="

bas64String=bas64String.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");

byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(bas64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: I was having this very same problem. I spent hours searching. I just never realised that I have to remove the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` to successfully decode it. However can you explain me why we need to remove it? Isn't this the standard format?